# The LiveUSB username

Tags: system-installation

I use a persistent usb with ubuntu and it asks me the user. Since I cannot access root I need the LiveUSB username, which I forgot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean you use Ubuntu live on a USB stick? There the user is **ubuntu** and **no password**.

Comment: multumesc, Alina!

Comment: I’m not Romanian, but you’re welcome (thanks to Google). :D

Answer (score 0):

Try to access as guest and type

```
cat /etc/passwd
```

You should find your username

Comment: the problem is that GUI starts atomatically. How could I access the terminal?

Comment: press Ctrl + Alt + T

Comment: that won't work on 'log in' screen

Comment: Ah, you can't login?

Comment: Try to follow my new answer

Comment: the live use seemed to be 'ubuntu', but your method worked as well. Thank You!